# Proof of the measurability of an integral process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given an square-integrable and adapted process $\Phi(s,\omega)$ with respect to a filtration $(\mathscr F_t)_{t>0}$ such that $P(\int_0^T|\Phi(s,\omega)|^2ds<\infty)=0$ . How can I prove that $$\int_0^q|\Phi(s,\omega)|^2ds$$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathscr F_q$.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1086971/36150 Alternatively, use an approximation by Riemann sums: $$\int_0^q |\Phi(s,\omega)|^2 \, ds = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n |\Phi(q j/n,\omega)|^2 \left( q\frac{j+1}{n}-q\frac{j}{n} \right).$$

Comment: @saz Thanks! Always great help from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough that $\Phi$ be aan adapted process. You need to know that $\Phi$ is *progressively measurable*, which means that for each fixed $q>0$ the map $\Omega\times[0,q]\ni(\omega,t)\mapsto \Phi_t(\omega)$ is $\mathcal F_q\otimes\mathcal B([0,q])$-measurable. This permits the application of Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: Could you emphasize the difference of progressively measurable and adapted?

Comment: "Progressive" amounts to joint measurability of the bi-variate function $(\omega,t)\mapsto\Phi_t(\omega)$. "Adapted" is the $\mathcal F_t$-measurability of $\omega\mapsto \Phi_t(\omega)$ for each *fixed* $t$.